# No phone state event received when ending second call in Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I registered a PHONE_STATE listener in order to detect when a call is started and ended by the user. In case anyone's wondering, I'm doing this strictly for fun and learning, so there's no privacy concerns.

Anyway, I noticed a problem when experimenting with telnet and emulator. In a specific scenario when one call is on hold and the second call (the active one) is ended, my listener receives no event. I was expecting it to at least receive another OFFHOOK when the first call is activated again, if not both IDLE + OFFHOOK. But there's nothing whatsoever.

On a related note, I also noticed there is no phone state event defined for putting a call on hold, which seems a bit strange to me, too.

Of course, the Android Log entries correctly reflect these events. The question is, how can I reliably detect them in code? Should I monitor the log itself (not sure if that's even possible) instead of relying on phone state listeners?

**I'm testing on API 15 on an emulator, via Xamarin Studio, so my code is C# + Xamarin.Android on Mono, not Java directly.** It may be that this behavior is simply a bug or omission in one of those layers, but it's more likely I'm simply missing something obvious.

FWIW, I haven't tested my code on a real device yet. I'm aware that certain hardware can behave a bit differently than what I see in emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's a problem. It's hard to detect when there is more than one call:

The first call can be detected by `idle to offhook` or `ringing to offhook` i.e. dialed or incoming. Now, when phone goes `offhook to ringing` we know second call is incoming. If you dial second call, its `offhook to offhook`, hence can't be detected from here. (you can listen to a dial broadcast though). Now if the second call is rejected we get `ringing to offhook` which is confusing with picking up a call.

IMHO just 3 states are not enough to track multiple calls, but that's what API supports for time being.